# Is it possible to have a remote eclipse workspace?

Tags: windows, eclipse, remote

I own a Windows machine and 2 Ubuntu's (one is a server and the other one laptop)

Right now I'm doing all of my coding on my Windows machine (it works perfectly), but since summer is right around the corner in The Netherlands I'd like to work outside sometimes. How can I sync the workspaces between Windows and Ubuntu (that includes the necessary library's)? Or better how can I sync the workspaces to my Ubuntu server and sync it back to my Windows machine and Ubuntu laptop without changing the paths everytime?

I saw a post about exporting a zip file with the related items, and then importing it on my laptop. Is it possible to make this work with a gitlab/github server?

The server has gitlab installed, but it doesn't sync the library's as well since that are other projects in my normal Windows workspace.

Thanks for all your help!

Tim

Comment: Assuming you'll have constant Internet access, you could put your workspace (and everything else, libraries, etc) on a remote server, mount it locally using SSHFS on your machine and finally tell Eclipse to use it. Another solution would be to put everything under version control, including the libraries needed by the project.

Comment: But the paths won't change that way right? The paths are full paths to the location of the file, so on window this is C:\Some lib.jar and on Ubuntu it is different. How do I change that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the remote system explorer.

https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh